# removing nested paths from vector of strings

Tags: c++, stl, unique

I have an `std::vector<std::string>paths` where each entry is a path and I want to remove all the paths that are sub-directories of another one.

If for example I have `root/dir1/`, `root/dir1/sub_dir/` and `root/dir2/`, the result should be `root/dir1/`, `root/dir2/`.

The way I've implemented it is by using `std::sort` + `std::unique` with a predicate that checks if `string2` starts with `string1`.

```
std::vector<std::string> paths = getPaths();

std::sort(paths.begin(), paths.end());
const auto to_erase = std::unique(paths.begin(), paths.end(), [](const std::string & s1, const std::string & s2) {
    return (s2.starts_with(s1) || s1.starts_with(s2));
});

paths.erase(to_erase, paths.end());
```

But since the predicate should be [symetrycal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) I wonder if in some implementation `std::unique` iterate from end to start, and in that case the result will be wrong.

Comment: You are fine. `std::unique` ① requires an _equivalence relation_, which you have, and ② keeps only the _first_, which you manage by stacking the parent path in front of the child path(s) using `std::sort`. The equivalence relation just means that **a** compares equal to **b**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your predicate *is* symmetric.

Let `p` be your predicate (the lambda), and `a` and `b` some strings, different from each other, but such that `p(a, b)` is true. Then either `a.starts_with(b)` or `b.starts_with(a)`.

If `a.starts_with(b)`, then `p(b, a)` is true because `s2.starts_with(s1)` is true in the lambda. Similarly, if `b.starts_with(a)`, then `p(b, a)` is true because `s1.starts_with(s2)` is true in the lambda.

So, if `p(a, b)`, then `p(b, a)` (and vice versa), which is the definition of a symmetric predicate.

It's not transitive though (`p("a/b", "a")` and `p("a", "a/c")` but not `p("a/b", "a/c")`), but I can't see a way this could pose a problem in practice. It could definitely lead to different results if the input isn't sorted, but yours is.

So your implementation is probably fine.